# Solution to the differential equation $\frac{f}{f^\prime}=\frac{f^\prime}{f^{\prime\prime}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering if anyone could please post the solution to the following differential equation for the function $f(x)$:

$$\frac{f}{f^\prime}=\frac{f^\prime}{f^{\prime\prime}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: In the context of differential equations it is *extremely* useful to memorize the particular chain rule $(\ln f)'=f\,'/f$ both forwards *and* backwards, because as it turns out you can use it backwards quite a lot.

Comment: right. thanks again!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\rm\bf Start$: Multiply through by $f\,''/f$ and integrate with respect to $x$:
$$\frac{f\,''}{f\,'}=\frac{f\,'}{f} \implies \ln (f\,')=\ln f+C.$$
Now exponentiate and solve another differential equation similarly...

---

$\rm\bf Finish$:

> $$f\,'=e^Cf=Af\implies f(x)=Be^{Ax}.$$

Comment: Ah, thanks! Did not know it should be that easy!

Answer (score 6):

$$
\frac{f}{f'} = \frac{f'}{f''} \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad \frac{f'}{f} = \frac{f''}{f'} \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad \int \frac{f'}{f} = \int\frac{f''}{f'} + C \qquad \Longleftrightarrow  \qquad \ln f = \ln f' + C
$$

Hence, taking exponentials on both sides,

$$
f = K f' \ ,
$$

where $K = e^C$. Renaming $K$ as $\frac{1}{K}$, this is the same as

$$
\frac{f'}{f} = K \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad \int \frac{f'}{f} = \int K + C  \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad \ln f = Kx + C \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad f(x) = A e^{Kx}
$$

where $A = e^C$.

Comment: There is a second solution with opposite sign for K (and maybe A?).